# What does "or virtually any..." mean?

Tags: word-usage

Consider the following sentence,

> "You can use Vim, Vi or **virtually** any text editor when writing C code".

Why put **virtually** in there? What difference does it make compared to if it wasn't there?

Note: Vim and Vi are text editors and C is a programming language.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? It could mean 'nearly or almost' source: https://www.google.co.jp/#q=virtually

Comment: Yes, I have. I just thought that maybe, there's other usage's  too. Since there isn't a reason to limit the statement to "almost any text editor".

Comment: In my mind, *virtually* is stronger than *nearly* or *almost*. It can indicate that the speaker doesn't know of any exceptions, and/or believes that there are no exceptions, but they also don't know for sure that there *aren't* any exceptions. *Nearly* or *almost* suggests that the speaker has an exception in mind, and is merely talking about the majority of cases.

Comment: @Era So it's basically just a way to have your back covered in case there are exceptions?

Comment: @Pkarls Yes, in my experience that's how it's usually used. You might not want to say *all* in case someone finds an exception and sends you an angry letter about it. Saying *virtually all* hedges the statement just enough to avoid backlash without suggesting that there are many exceptions to what you're claiming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that in the speaker's mind there are some limits. He may or may not be aware of exactly what they are, but he doesn't want to make a blanket statement and have to quibble later about some rare corner case that disproves an assertion of "any text editor".

E.G. A few decades ago I might have said "virtually all methods of home heating pollute the atmosphere" with the mental reservation that there were probably a few hippie communes in Vermont that heated purely with solar power.